# How to get next 2 nodes in HTML + HTMLAgilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a table in the HTML code below:

```
<table style="padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td><h3>My Regional Financial Office</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&#160;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h3>My Address</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>000 Test Ave S Ste 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Golden Valley, MN 00000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:submitForm('0000','0000000');">Get Directions</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&#160;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get the inner text of the next 2 `<tr>` tags after the tablerow containing the text "My Address?"

Comment: Where? In code-behind or Javascript?

Comment: in code, i want the output be a string="000 Test Ave S Ste 000,Golden Valley, MN 00000";

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following XPath :

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var tdOfInterests = 
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//tr[td/h3[.='My Address']]/following-sibling::tr[position() <= 2]/td");
foreach (HtmlNode td in tdOfInterests)
{
    //given html input in question following code will print following 2 lines:
    //000 Test Ave S Ste 000
    //Golden Valley, MN 00000
    Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
}
```

The key of above XPath is using `following-sibling` with `position()` filter.

**UPDATE :**

A bit explanation about the XPath used in this answer :

```
//tr[td/h3[.='My Address']]
```

above part select `<tr>` element that has :

- child `<td>` element that has child `<h3>` element with value equals 
  'My Address'

---

```
/following-sibling::tr[position() <= 2]
```

next part select following `<tr>` element with position <=2 from *current `<tr>` element* (the one selected by previous XPath part)

```
/td
```

the last part select child `<td>` element from current `<tr>` element

Comment: working as a charm! thanks, can you please explain a bit of its XPath?

Comment: Check **UPDATE** section. Can't find a better way to explain, hope you get it.